# ¿Cómo crear Redes Neuronales en Python?

Tags: python, redes-neuronales

### Hola a Todos!

Hace tiempo que estoy interesado en la creación de Redes Neuronales con Python. He utilizado la librería **Scikit Learn**, pero me gustaría aprender a crearlas sin esta. ¿Cómo funcionan?

Esto es solo por mera curiosidad, debido a que no me gusta usar algo sin haber intentado o entendido como es su funcionamiento. Entonces, si mi cabeza no explota en el intento ;D, podré entender y realizar lo que hace Scikit por mi propia cuenta.

**Muchas Gracias**

Comment: Matías, la respuesta rápida es "depende", depende del esfuerzo que inviertas, ten en cuenta que no se trata solo de entender funciones leyendo el código, para los temas relacionados a ML deberías tener una fuerte base en matemáticas. Pero lo que te pueda decir no van a ser más que una opinión y lamentablemente sabes que las preguntas basadas en estas suele terminar cerradas. Suerte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad, no es complicado hacer una red neuronal sencilla, puedes seguir este enlace para verlo:

https://underc0de.org/foro/python/neurona-artificial-simple-en-python/

Ahora bien, las librerías, a parte de la sencillez de una simple neurona y una estructura de capas muy limitada, incorporan métodos avanzados de aprendizaje, salidas especiales, funciones distintas a sigma, lectura de datos y su transformación a binario, técnicas para realizar tareas complejas y un sinfín de mejoras respecto a los códigos más simples como el del ejemplo.

Por ejemplo, existe una técnica llamada backpropagation (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagaci%C3%B3n_hacia_atr%C3%A1s) que permite entrenar la red neuronal de forma supervisada y otras muchas que seguro la librería que comentas, ya traen de serie. Implementar en tu código dichas funciones requerirá entonces mucho tiempo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Añado como comentario un enlace que me parece muy práctico para tal fin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8AeOXa_FqU&list=PL-Ogd76BhmcCO4VeOlIH93BMT5A_kKAXp